# Create a New array from given array where each element's length is one more than previous element, Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create new Array from old array where each elements length is greater than its previous element.
I have a old array like below:

```
Arr=[[2,3],[1,2],[2,4,5],[6,6,3],[3,2,1],[4,2,3],[4,2,1,2],[2,1,4,5]]
```

Now I have to create a new array like below from above array:

```
newArr = [[2,3],[2,4,5],[4,2,1,2]]
```

Using Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We loop over all array and if current length less then next, we push element in result and change a current length

```
const findArray = () => {
  let currentLength = 0
  const result = []
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
    if (arr[i].length > currentLength) {
      result.push(arr[i])
      currentLength = arr[i].length
    }
  }
  return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**I wood here to demonstrate this code with real value (the output is printed in screen)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to create an array, then display its length.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   
  var Arr=[[2,3],[1,2],[2,4,5],[6,6,3],[3,2,1],[4,2,3],[4,2,1,2],[2,1,4,5]];
  
var text = ""; 
var len=0;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++) { 
 if (len < Arr[i].length )
  {text += Arr[i] + "<br>"; len=Arr[i].length;}
}
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;


}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Result is:

```
2,3
2,4,5
4,2,1,2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a closure over the next wanted length and filter the array by checking the index or actual length. If one of the both conditions is `true`, set `l` to the next expected length.

```js
const
    array = [[2, 3], [1, 2], [2, 4, 5], [6, 6, 3], [3, 2, 1], [4, 2, 3], [4, 2, 1, 2], [2, 1, 4, 5]],
    result = array.filter(
        (l => ({ length }) => (!l || l === length) && (l = length + 1))
        (0)
    );

console.log(result);
```